# How to search for language syntax in Google?

Tags: ruby, operators

My current question is what does the << operator do in Ruby? But my real question is how would I search Google to find the answer?

Comment: definitely not programming related ("how to find something on google")

Comment: Yeah @Cletus, and your "Good PHP hosting options?" was just number one on the "top programming questions" list.

Comment: I think this question is related to programming than "Good PHP hosting options?".

Comment: I agree, but I've made it a community wiki anyway to avoid any problems... although now it's doing quite well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google for "ruby operators" (without the quotes), open the first link in a new window, use your browser to search for '<<' (without the quotes).

Comment: Already thought of that, but thanks. I wanted something a bit more specific.

Comment: Months later, I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 4):

"shift left operator ruby"

Google will only find something if you search for words and numbers...

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, this approach only works when you know that << means left shift ;)

Comment: That's true Rowland. I tried searching on "double less-than signs ruby" without the quotes and the result was okay.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy to use a search engine other than Google for your googling, then try using symbolhound.com

[<< ruby](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%3C%3C%20ruby)

Answer (score 1):

[Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) lets you search public source code repositories, so perhaps you can find [examples of "<<" in Ruby](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=%22%3C%3C%22+lang%3Aruby&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code) to help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "ruby operators" search Joe Casadonte suggested to find the words you're after, then google using those words?